# Convert Minutes to milliseconds Java/android

Tags: java, android, datetime

I am trying to convert given number of minutes into milliseconds.

For eg: 15mins or 20mins or 44mins should be converted to milliseconds programmatically.

I tried the below:

```
Calendar alarmCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

alarmCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,15);

long alarmTime = alarmCalendar.getTimeInMillis();

Log.e("Milli", "seconds"+alarmTime);
```

This doesn't give the right value? What is the best way to convert this?

Comment: 15 minutes in milliseconds is 15 * 60 * 1000. What am I missing?

Comment: 1 minute = 60 * seconds, 1 second = 1000 millis => 1 minute = 60000 millis. This is basic math!

Comment: getTimeInMillis() returns the current time as UTC milliseconds from the epoch.

Comment: @ArtooDetoo I know this is a simple calculation. I don't want to use the calculation instead i would like to use something like RC's answer.

Comment: ... which internally does the same calculation... ;)

Comment: You can create a method doing this stuff, instead of doing this directly. In this way you'll have a simple, fast and all-api-levels valid way to convert minutes to millisecs

Answer (score 191, accepted):

```
TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(yourMinutes)
```

see [`TimeUnit`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) javadoc (android)

Comment: Another option / a bit more generic:
Long periodInMillis = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(yourMinutes, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

Answer (score 17):

```
int minutes = 42;
long millis = minutes * 60 * 1000;
```

Answer (score 8):

1 minute = 60000 millisecs.

```
int minutes = 1;
long milliseconds = minutes * 60000;
```

Comment: I know this...I don't want to use the calculations.

Answer (score 4):

In Java 8+, use `java.time`.

```
java.time.Duration.ofMinutes(15).toMillis();
```

Comment: Call requires API level 26 . but right now most app support minimum API 23

Comment: @Dharmishta with Java 8+, everyone can use desugaring library without requiring a minimum api level and have fun. Check [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) for more

Answer (score 0):

This answer is in reference to Android using Kotlin-

So if you are using MaterialTimePicker or TimePicker then you can get the hours and minutes values stored in the picker. Then use `TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(picker.hour.toLong())` and `TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(picker.minutes.toLong())` to convert the received time to milliseconds and then add both the values to get the total time in Milliseconds which you can further use to store in Room Database for entering time and fetching when required.

Code for reference :

```
binding.timeStart.setOnClickListener {
            openTimePicker()
            picker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener {
                val h = picker.hour
                val m = picker.minute
                binding.timeStart.text = "$h:$m"
                Timber.d("Start Time - $h: $m")
                try {
                    val hour = TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(h.toLong())
                    val minute = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(m.toLong())
                    val totalTime = hour + minute

                    Timber.d("Hour - $hour, Minute - $minute, Total = $totalTime")
                    timeStart = totalTime

                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    Timber.d("$e")
                }
            }
        }


 private fun openTimePicker() {
        picker = MaterialTimePicker.Builder()
            .setTimeFormat(TimeFormat.CLOCK_12H)
            .setHour(12)
            .setMinute(10)
            .setTitleText("Set Start Time")
            .build()
        picker.show(childFragmentManager, "TAG")
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

This gives you the time in milli.

```
long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
Handler handler = new Handler(); 
long waitTime = currentTime + (15*60*1000);
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
     public void run() { 
          // Alert or do something here.
     } 
}, waitTime);
```

This piece of code sleeps for 15 minutes and then executes the handler's run method. This way you can raise an alarm etc...